# rsync & source/dest & tar.gz beginner thing, too primitive for FAQs:

Tags: local, copying

actually, I AM being ashame about my question (both parts of it) but could anyone help me with my problem?

*) I have read how to use rsync BUT could anyone give me an example how to type it in?
rsync -a source dest 
is comprehensible BUT how do I write source and dest? 
(they are called sda1 and sda2 in my linux) 
is it "rsync -a sda1 sda2" (for example, for copying all of sda1 to sda2 ?)

and

*) I have downloaded a driver and an executable for linux (they are .tar.gz) 
since I dont care about the MD5 key (I would not know how to use that, either) 
my problem is only 
a) in which folder /root/??? do I have to copy the contents of the driver .tar.gz 
(or does that need an extra installation routine? I want to use it with DSL damn small linux from CD without installing the -- I think -- debian which it is, so I still should be able to copy it into a virtual disk part in memory claimed to be used by DSL) ? 
and 
b) in which folder /root/??? do I have to copy the executable (and how do I start it) ? 
(or, same question, does that need an extra installation?)

thank you for your patience, whoever would care about me

Regina

Comment: These questions are a better fit for either http://unix.stackexchange.com or [SU], as they don't appear to be related to professional system administration (see our [FAQ]).

Comment: I would like to answer the MD5 part since you can use in in the future with a lot of programs. Simply run `md5 filename`. It will return an output similar to this one: `MD5 (filename) = db24a67c07085d581763af058f34129d`. (The actual returned value should differ). You compare the value stored in a known safe this_should_be_the_value.md5 file with the one you generated. If someone tampered with the file then the values do not match.

Answer (score 1):

First, `sda1` and `sda2` are likely partition names, not mounted file systems. You will need to check if they are already mounted. To do this, use the command `mount` without any parameters. If they don't appear in this list, you have to mount them first, e.g. with `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/data1` and `mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/data2`.

If this is done, you can just use

```
rsync -av /mnt/data1 /mnt/data2
```

If one or both are already mounted, replace `/mnt/data1/` (or `data2` with the respective mount point).

Also, should you actually have two directories named `sda1` and `sda2`, the command will in fact be

```
rsync -av /path/to/sda1 /path/to/sda2
```

Please rephrase the second question, stating what you have and what you want to do, without irrelevant additional infos like the MD5 part. Also, try to use the formatting tools that are available to make your text more readable. As it stands, it is quite confusing.